# Yii2 : how to use distinct , groupby , sum and where conditions

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want execute below query in using `Yii2` syntax selection query,

```
select distinct pfs_id, unitprice, sum(qty)
from order_items
where order_id= id
and item_farm_id = id
group By pfs_id
```

I tried several times but still not getting luck,

Please any one help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query return you desire result as array.

```
$data=ModelName::find()  //replace your model name here
->select('distinct(pfs_id),unitprice,sum(qty)')
->where(['order_id'=>id,'item_farm_id'=>id])
->groupBy('pfs_id')
->asArray->all();
```

You can also use alias:

```
$data=ModelName::find()
->select('distinct(pfs_id) as pfs_id,unitprice,sum(qty) as sum_of_qty')
->where(['order_id'=>id,'item_farm_id'=>id])
->groupBy('pfs_id')
->asArray->all();
```