# How to use DISTINCT ON in Yii2 Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am new to Yii2. I need a Distinct On query. My current query is:

```
$distinct_values=  TournamentResult :: find()->where(['tournament_id'=>$tournament->id])->distinct('member_id')->all();
```

I am trying to get the distinct members, Once a member is fetch do not fetch it again. But the above query is not fetching the distinct records based on `member_id`.

Comment: DISTINCT ON is PostgreSQL feature, it is not implemented in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get the required output. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: [Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816832/yii2-how-to-use-distinct-groupby-sum-and-where-conditions)

Comment: I think this is dublicate to [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361571/yii2-how-to-write-distinct-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31361571), distinct requires an extra `->distinct()->` operator

Comment: You are mixing up `DISTINCT` and `DISTINCT ON`.